# TFS 2013 Build: Cannot leave solution/project files field blank

Tags: powershell, tfs, build, tfsbuild

I'm using the build process template that comes with TFS 2013 (TfvcTemplate.12.xaml). I want to create a new build definition that runs a bunch of PowerShell scripts; however, I do not have anything .NET to build. TF build does not seem to like that. I'm getting this error below when leaving the solution/project files field blank. Is there any way to get around this?

> TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \MyProjectRoot\MyBuildDefinition:
>
> Exception Message:
>
> The process parameter ProjectsToBuild is required but no value was set. A value must be set on the definition or when the build is queued (Category: #200 Build, Display Name: 1. Projects). (type ArgumentException)
>
> Exception Stack Trace:
>
> ```
> at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowInstance.ValidateParameters(BuildWorkflowDefinition definition, IDictionary`2 passedInParameterValues) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowInstance.Initialize(BuildWorkflowDefinition definition, IDictionary`2 dataContext) 
> at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowManager.TryStartWorkflow(WorkflowRequest request, WorkflowManagerActivity activity, BuildWorkflowInstance& workflowInstance, Exception& error, Boolean& syncLockTaken)
> ```

Comment: What are you actually attempting to do by running a bunch of PowerShell scripts?

Comment: To package 3rd party files that had already been built; hence, the reason why I do not need to run MSBuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TFS 2015 (or Visual Studio Online) the new TFS Build system no longer has this limitation.

In TFS 2013 what I often do (to avoid having to muck around with the workflow), is just provide a dummy MSBuild .proj file that does nothing.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" InitialTargets="Build">
  <Target Name="Build">
    <Message Text="This MSBuild is a placeholder and does nothing" /> 
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I ended up doing: using a dummy MSBuild .proj file that does nothing and it works.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Dylan's solution, but something very similar that I do is to create an empty Solution file (.sln) in visual studio and mention that within the build definition/workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create your own Process Template (you can probably steal quite a bit from the standard template), and you'll need to rip out the `Run MsBuild for Project` activity as well as the parameters that are defined specifically for that activity (that will be quite a bit of the default template).

That should allow you to jump directly to the powershell sections.

Comment: Thanks @jessehouwing. Although your solution sounds great, I ended going with solution suggested by Dylan Smith.